# R rgl plot value not showing on axis

Tags: r, axis, rgl

I'm using the rgl package in r to plot some data. As done here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-3d-geographical-plots-in-r-using-rgl/

For some reason the scale does not align with the graph.

I changed the scale of the X and Z axis to increase the relief, which I initially thought was causing the issue, but in the example below, even if I change 0.02 to 1 the issue occurs.

```
library(rgl)

rdata <- c(0.8926,0.8986,0.9478,0.9672,0.916,0.912,0.9324,0.9532,0.9488,0.9376,0.921,0.927,0.9728,0.956,0.9318,0.9202)
labs <-c(100,200,500,1000)

rmatrix <- matrix(rdata, nrow=4,ncol=4,)
dimnames(rmatrix) <- list(labs,labs)

y <- as.matrix(rmatrix)
x <- 0.02*(1:nrow(y))
z <- 0.02*(1:ncol(y))

rgl.surface(x, z, y, color="red", back="lines")
axis3d('x--', labels=row.names(rmatrix),color="black")
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks for your help! 
Mat

Comment: reproducible example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without supplying a value to the `labels` argument in `axis3d`, I get an axis with six tick marks. Since you supply a vector with only four values to the `labels` argument, it looks like `axis3d` recycles those values to cover all the tick marks.

Tell `axis3d` at what data values you'd like to place the tick marks by supplying a value to the `at` argument:

```
axis3d('x--', at = x, labels=row.names(rmatrix),color="black")
```

---

p.s. I had to add the following line before `rgl.surface()` to avoid getting a segfault

```
rgl.open()
```

Comment: me too (on the segfault); probably worth reporting to the maintainer if you have a minute to do so ...